# TCP received data sporadically misplaced

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp, buffering

I am communicating with a piece of lab equipment over TCP. The equipment has a command set and will reply to each command with a confirmation that the command was received and any data requested in the command. The issue is that it appears that when using, for instance, `socket.recv()`, or any of the variations thereof to get the response from the equipment after I `send()` a command, the method returns when *any* data is received rather than when *all the data I want/expect* is received. This causes some of the data to not be in the `recv()` call I expect and instead showing up in the next call.

A solution I am considering is handling the received data entirely separately/asynchronously from the sent data and parsing it as it comes in using repeated `recv()` calls, but this seems like a lot of overhead when I imagine there could be a simple way to use what I know about the received data (e.g. it always ends with a carriage return and line feed, but I don't know how long the message is) to wait until the entire message is received *and no longer*.

To summarize: is there an existing way to receive data via TCP in a more controlled way so the data winds up where I expect?

Comment: That's how TCP works. [TCP sockets are streams of bytes, not streams of messages.](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html) If you want a stream of messages, you have to build that on top of a loop (or async callbacks, or whatever) around `recv` and a buffer and code that implements some message framing protocol of your choice.

Comment: I was just curious whether there's a prebuilt way to handle framing, possibly from a higher level libary or package I can install. I don't think what I've described is a new problem and I'm just a little surprised I'm not finding what I'm looking for.

Comment: There are a million protocols, ranging from simple stuff like netstrings or jsonlines or up to things like xmlrpc over http. Plus a half dozen ways to implement protocol handling, which depend on how you’re reading off the network in the first place (blocking reads with or without threads, select loop, callbacks, asyncio…). Most combinations have a stdlib or third-party library that does most of the work, but first you have to pick one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TCP sockets are streams of bytes, not streams of messages.](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html). If you want a stream of messages, you have to define a protocol on top of that, and code to handle sending and receiving data in that protocol.

If your messages are all strings, and never include newline characters, probably the simplest protocol is just separating the messages with newlines. I think you’ve already worked that out, you just need to know how to implement it.

If the way you’re handling the network is a blocking `recv` (whether in the main loop of your program, or in the loop of a thread dedicated to reading off the socket), there’s built in support for this protocol: call `sock.makefile` with an appropriate mode (`r` plus an encoding if you want Unicode strings for your messages, `rb` if you want raw bytes), and you can use it like a file—e.g., a `for msg in file:` loop, or a while loop over `file.readline()` until you get an exception (meaning socket error) or empty string (meaning EOF—a clean socket close).

If your messages *can* have newlines in them, you may still be able to use this. Just escape the messages (maybe using full backslash-escape so they’re always readable, for easy debugging, or maybe just `msg.replace('\\', '\\\\').replace('\n', '\\n')`) before sending, and unescape on receiving.

Under the covers, this works the same way a normal file object does with disk files: when you ask for the next line, if it already has a complete line in the buffer, it just splits it off and returns it; if not, it reads buffers and appends them onto what it has until it finally gets a newline, then splits off the first complete line and returns it to you. So, it will never block waiting for two packets if the first packet contained a newline. But it will also never give you a “no complete message yet” to deal with; it’ll just keep blocking until it reads enough packets to get the next newline.

It is worth learning how to build something like this from scratch at some point—but meanwhile, you can just use what’s already there. If you’re interested, the short version (without good error handling, and some useful optimizations) looks something like this:

```
def messages(sock):
    buf = b''
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(8192)
        if not data: break
        buf += data
        lines = buf.split('\n')
        for line in lines[:-1]:
            yield line.decode('utf8')
        buf = lines[-1]
    # Should leftover bytes after the last newline be a message, an error, or ignored? Picking arbitrarily...
    if buf: yield buf.decode('utf8')
```

But of course it’s simpler to just call 'makefile' (and that way you do get the error handling and optimization, too).

Answer (score 0):

Based on what abarnert suggested, I can use what I know about the data I'm receiving to frame it. Specifically, the thing I'm talking to throws a lot of trash lines at me that I don't want, so I just search each line for the substring that I know goes with what I care about:

```
def send_message_return_response(sock, sock_file, message, substring):
   #discard remainders from commands I sent but didn't read back due to not caring
   sock_file.flush()
   sock.send(message)
   response = ''
   while substring not in response: response = sock_file.readline()
   return response
```

Comment: You might consider separating the reception into a generator function which only yields valid responses.  This would allow your sending and receiving code to be decoupled  and might allow for more graceful handling of timeouts and other issues and exceptions.